# Two sync QGrapchisView layers miss aligned scene rect after zoom event, but aligned after pan events

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt5, qgraphicsview

I have two classes of edited `QGrapchicsView`, one (`GraphicsView`) shows lines and it enables zoom and pan. The second class (`PolygonGrapchisView`) only updates the scene rect to match that of the first class `GraphicsView` from a signal receive from the first class. The pan events is triggered by the middle button

**The Issue**

The `PolygonGrapchisView` class receives the signal from the `GraphicsView` class and updates the scene rect to match the extent on both classes.

Regardless of the position or zoom level, the signal from the `mousePressEvent`, `mouseReleaseEvent` and `mouseMoveEvent` functions (pan events) from the `GraphicsView` class set the scene rect on both classes correctly. What I mean by correctly, is that it sets the rect scene in the two classes so that the polygons and the lines stay in the same position relative to each other, after the events.

When I try to do the same with `wheelEvent` (zoom event) it has two behaviors. The first one is when the zoom event is done when the scroll bar is full (occupies the whole horizontal and vertical bars, there is no room to move the scrollbar) or we are doing a zoom out, here it works 'correctly'.

The second, is when we began to zoom in until the scroll bars activates
and start to have room to move, the signal to match the scene rect fails. It miss aligns the two graphicsview classes, meaning that the polygon and the line do not stay in the same position relative to each other but start to overlap or partway from each other. You can fix this miss alignment issue if you stop moving the wheel and just press the middle bottom and pan the scene.

This is the initial status of the plot, this is how it should stay after all the mouse events.

[image]

This is the one where the failure occurs when you do a zoom in until you activate the scroll bars.

[image]
**Expected behavior**

The scene from the `PolygonGrapchisView` class is updated 'correctly' when we do a pan or zoom event in the `GraphicsView` class, regardless from the  zoom level or the position of the scrollbars. It keeps the relative distance between polygon and lines during and after the mouse events.

Code

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import sys


class PolygonGraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, scene, parent=None):
        super(PolygonGraphicsView, self).__init__(scene, parent)
        # Set the anchor point for zooming and resizing
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)

        # Disable the scrollbars
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QRectF, QtGui.QTransform)
    def setBounds(self, rect_scene, transform_matrix):
        #set scene rect
        self.setSceneRect(rect_scene)
        # Update the transformation matrix to match GraphicsView
        self.setTransform(transform_matrix)



class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    #señal para cambiar el viewport del qgrapichsview de los poligonos
    scene_rect_changed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QRectF, QtGui.QTransform)

    def __init__(self, scene, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__(scene, parent)


        # "variables iniciales"
        self.pos_init_class = None
        self.scale_factor = 1.5

        # # Set the anchor point for zooming and resizing
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)

    def send_polygon_graphicsView_update(self):
        # Emit the scene_rect_changed signal with the transformation matrix
        new_rect = self.sceneRect()
        self.scene_rect_changed.emit(new_rect, self.transform())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        pos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        # "pan mouse"
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:
            self.pos_init_class = pos
            #update position
            self.send_polygon_graphicsView_update()
        else:
            super(GraphicsView, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        # pan
        if self.pos_init_class and event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:
            self.pos_init_class = None
            # update position
            self.send_polygon_graphicsView_update()
        else:
            super(GraphicsView, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pos_init_class:
            # "pan"
            delta = self.pos_init_class - self.mapToScene(event.pos())
            r = self.mapToScene(self.viewport().rect()).boundingRect()
            self.setSceneRect(r.translated(delta))
            # update position
            self.send_polygon_graphicsView_update()

        super(GraphicsView, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        old_pos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

        # Determine the zoom factor
        if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
            zoom_factor = self.scale_factor
        else:
            zoom_factor = 1 / self.scale_factor

        # Apply the transformation to the view
        transform = QtGui.QTransform()
        transform.translate(old_pos.x(), old_pos.y())
        transform.scale(zoom_factor, zoom_factor)
        transform.translate(-old_pos.x(), -old_pos.y())

        # Get the current transformation matrix and apply the new transformation to it
        current_transform = self.transform()
        self.setTransform(transform * current_transform)

        # update position
        self.send_polygon_graphicsView_update()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # apply transparent style sheet
        self.this_style_sheet = """
                   background-color: transparent;
                   selection-background-color:transparent;
               """

        self.transparent_viewport_style_sheet = """
                   background-color: transparent;
               """

        # Geometry of the window
        self.geometry = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 500)
        self.scene_rect_value = QtCore.QRectF(721200.96, -9679800.97, 500, -500)
        self.setGeometry(self.geometry)

        # Create central widget and layout
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        # Polygon graphics view widget (bottom layer)
        self.polygon_scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.polygon_graphicsView = PolygonGraphicsView(scene=self.polygon_scene, parent=self)
        self.polygon_graphicsView.setSceneRect(self.scene_rect_value)
        layout.addWidget(self.polygon_graphicsView, 0, 0)

        # Graphics view widget (top layer)
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsView = GraphicsView(scene=self.scene, parent=self)
        self.graphicsView.setSceneRect(self.scene_rect_value)
        self.graphicsView.setStyleSheet(self.this_style_sheet)
        self.graphicsView.viewport().setStyleSheet(self.transparent_viewport_style_sheet)
        layout.addWidget(self.graphicsView, 0, 0)

        #señal para el qgrapichsview de poligonos
        self.graphicsView.scene_rect_changed.connect(self.polygon_graphicsView.setBounds)

        # Dummy line and polygon generator
        self.dummy_lines_polygons()


    def dummy_lines_polygons(self):

        polygon_list = [[[721278.105, 9679978.402], [721378.918, 9679958.288], [721395.355, 9680058.781], [721294.491, 9680079.538]],
                        [[721398.840, 9679959.473], [721486.867, 9679930.441], [721502.381, 9680029.483], [721416.757, 9680055.152]]]
        for pol in polygon_list:
            polygon = QtGui.QPolygonF()
            for item in pol:
                x = item[0]
                y = -item[1]
                polygon.append(QtCore.QPointF(x, y))
            polygon_item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPolygonItem(polygon)
            brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255))
            polygon_item.setBrush(brush)
            self.polygon_scene.addItem(polygon_item)

        # add some lines to the line view
        line_list = [[[721385.198, 9679948.971], [721404.402, 9680064.235] ], [[721404.402, 9680064.235], [721512.651, 9680035.611]]]
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))
        for line in line_list:
            x1 = line[0][0]
            y1 = -line[0][1]
            x2 = line[1][0]
            y2 = -line[1][1]
            line = QtWidgets.QGraphicsLineItem(x1, y1, x2, y2)
            line.setPen(pen)
            self.scene.addItem(line)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: There are some issues with your implementation. First of all, the two scenes are not consistent: the first one has a possible scene "range" that is `-50, -50, 50, 50`, while the second is `0, 0, 500, 500`, which makes both translation and scaling inconsistent. Then, emitting the view's scene rect alone might be both not enough and invalid: when you zoom, you are not changing the scene rect, which is correct, but the provided info is not sufficient for the other view. Please clarify what should be the expected behavior with those two different scenes (considering the different bounds).

Comment: Also, please fix the code by properly using layout managers and *reasonable* sizes: 2500x1500 is really too much and doesn't make a lot of sense considering the very small scene bounds you're using. In theory, you should not even set fixed geometries at all, and just leave that to the layout manager. Besides, it doesn't make any sense to use `setGeometry()` with the *same* geometry for the main window **and** the graphics view.

Comment: Hi @musicamante thank you for the reply.  I understand that the two scenes are not consistent because of the random creation, I will change it.  As for the size I did not know you were not supposed to do that, I will  just make it whole screen. As far as the layout manager, this is a similar set up as the one as used in the real app, so I tried to keep as is, which is a big code so is hard to refactor. I will change the data to actual data. Also, I will explain the problem further in detail to make it clear and  have the example also clearly demonstrates it. Than you for your time.

Comment: @musicamante I updated the question, I hope it is more clear now. greetings and thank you.

Comment: Please check your examples before posting. Right now we can only see *one* view, and that's because you're still using `setGeometry()` with the same rect for the window and the views: as said above, you *must* use layouts. I understand that refactoring to an example may be hard, but it's an important step for you (sometimes it results in finding the solution on your own) and us (it makes it easier to focus on the problem). Note that this isn't just pedantry: setting the sceneRect may change the view's size hint and could change the result in the visible region of the scene of a proper layout.

Comment: hi @musicamante, I posted  a figure of what I see, I do see both scenes and polygon and lines. I am going to try to make it in to a layout to see if I have the same effect. Thank you again.  I will update the question again.

Comment: Hi @musicamante, I changed the code to use layouts, I don't know if this is a correct way, I will re do the code  if it is not.  This reproduces my problem, Thank you very much for the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anybody else is going into this. The issue was that once the zoom in activated the scroll bars, the first and second class had different values, so it caused the miss alignment issue. I solved this by including the first class values of the scroll bars and the apply it to the second class. I don't know if this is the best way to accomplish this, so If anybody has a better answer everything is welcome.

**Code**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
import sys


class PolygonGraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):

    def __init__(self, scene, parent=None):
        super(PolygonGraphicsView, self).__init__(scene, parent)
        # Set the anchor point for zooming and resizing
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)

        # Disable the scrollbars
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QRectF, QtGui.QTransform, int, int)
    def setBounds(self, rect_scene, transform_matrix, h_value, v_value):
        # set scene rect
        self.setSceneRect(rect_scene)
        # Update the transformation matrix to match GraphicsView
        self.setTransform(transform_matrix)
        # Set the scrollbar values
        self.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(h_value)
        self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(v_value)

        # print second class scroll bar values
        print('horizontal PolygonGraphicsView:', self.horizontalScrollBar().value())
        print('vertical PolygonGraphicsView:', self.verticalScrollBar().value())
        print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------')

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, int)
    def setScrollBarValues(self, h_value, v_value):
        self.horizontalScrollBar().setValue(h_value)
        self.verticalScrollBar().setValue(v_value)


class GraphicsView(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    #señal para cambiar el viewport del qgrapichsview de los poligonos
    scene_rect_changed = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QRectF, QtGui.QTransform, int, int)

    def __init__(self, scene, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsView, self).__init__(scene, parent)


        # "variables iniciales"
        self.pos_init_class = None
        self.scale_factor = 1.5

        # # Set the anchor point for zooming and resizing
        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)

    def send_polygon_graphicsView_update(self):
        # Emit the scene_rect_changed signal with the transformation matrix and scrollbar values
        new_rect = self.sceneRect()
        h_value = self.horizontalScrollBar().value()
        v_value = self.verticalScrollBar().value()
        self.scene_rect_changed.emit(new_rect, self.transform(), h_value, v_value)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        pos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())
        # "pan mouse"
        if event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:
            self.pos_init_class = pos
            #update position
            self.send_polygon_graphicsView_update()
        else:
            super(GraphicsView, self).mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        # pan
        if self.pos_init_class and event.button() == QtCore.Qt.MiddleButton:
            self.pos_init_class = None
            # update position
            self.send_polygon_graphicsView_update()
        else:
            super(GraphicsView, self).mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.pos_init_class:
            # "pan"
            delta = self.pos_init_class - self.mapToScene(event.pos())
            r = self.mapToScene(self.viewport().rect()).boundingRect()
            self.setSceneRect(r.translated(delta))
            # update position
            self.send_polygon_graphicsView_update()

        super(GraphicsView, self).mouseMoveEvent(event)

    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        old_pos = self.mapToScene(event.pos())

        # Determine the zoom factor
        if event.angleDelta().y() > 0:
            zoom_factor = self.scale_factor
        else:
            zoom_factor = 1 / self.scale_factor

        # Apply the transformation to the view
        transform = QtGui.QTransform()
        transform.translate(old_pos.x(), old_pos.y())
        transform.scale(zoom_factor, zoom_factor)
        transform.translate(-old_pos.x(), -old_pos.y())

        # Get the current transformation matrix and apply the new transformation to it
        current_transform = self.transform()
        self.setTransform(transform * current_transform)

        # print scroll bar values
        print('horizontal GraphicsView:', self.horizontalScrollBar().value())
        print('vertical GraphicsView:', self.verticalScrollBar().value())
        print('-----------------------------------------------------------------------')

        # update position
        self.send_polygon_graphicsView_update()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # apply transparent style sheet
        self.this_style_sheet = """
                   background-color: transparent;
                   selection-background-color:transparent;
               """

        self.transparent_viewport_style_sheet = """
                   background-color: transparent;
               """

        # Geometry of the window
        self.geometry = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 500)
        self.scene_rect_value = QtCore.QRectF(721200.96, -9679800.97, 500, -500)
        self.setGeometry(self.geometry)

        # Create central widget and layout
        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        # Polygon graphics view widget (bottom layer)
        self.polygon_scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.polygon_graphicsView = PolygonGraphicsView(scene=self.polygon_scene, parent=self)
        self.polygon_graphicsView.setSceneRect(self.scene_rect_value)
        layout.addWidget(self.polygon_graphicsView, 0, 0)

        # Graphics view widget (top layer)
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
        self.graphicsView = GraphicsView(scene=self.scene, parent=self)
        self.graphicsView.setSceneRect(self.scene_rect_value)
        self.graphicsView.setStyleSheet(self.this_style_sheet)
        self.graphicsView.viewport().setStyleSheet(self.transparent_viewport_style_sheet)
        layout.addWidget(self.graphicsView, 0, 0)

        #señal para el qgrapichsview de poligonos
        self.graphicsView.scene_rect_changed.connect(self.polygon_graphicsView.setBounds)

        # Dummy line and polygon generator
        self.dummy_lines_polygons()


    def dummy_lines_polygons(self):

        polygon_list = [[[721278.105, 9679978.402], [721378.918, 9679958.288], [721395.355, 9680058.781], [721294.491, 9680079.538]],
                        [[721398.840, 9679959.473], [721486.867, 9679930.441], [721502.381, 9680029.483], [721416.757, 9680055.152]]]
        for pol in polygon_list:
            polygon = QtGui.QPolygonF()
            for item in pol:
                x = item[0]
                y = -item[1]
                polygon.append(QtCore.QPointF(x, y))
            polygon_item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPolygonItem(polygon)
            brush = QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(0, 0, 255))
            polygon_item.setBrush(brush)
            self.polygon_scene.addItem(polygon_item)

        # add some lines to the line view
        line_list = [[[721385.198, 9679948.971], [721404.402, 9680064.235] ], [[721404.402, 9680064.235], [721512.651, 9680035.611]]]
        pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))
        for line in line_list:
            x1 = line[0][0]
            y1 = -line[0][1]
            x2 = line[1][0]
            y2 = -line[1][1]
            line = QtWidgets.QGraphicsLineItem(x1, y1, x2, y2)
            line.setPen(pen)
            self.scene.addItem(line)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```