# Vispy canvas can not be set to transparent background when given a rgba color

Tags: pyqt5, vispy

I have a pyqt5 app that sets a `Vispy` widget as top layer and a `QGrapchisView` as  the bottom layer. I draw a sample line in both canvas with similar geometry.

**Problem**

Even when setting the rgba with an alpha channel as zero or close to zero, the `Vispy` canvas widget it is not transparent. I try to make the pyqt5 widget native widget transparent as well but it does not make a transparent background.

**Expected behavior**

The red line from the `QgraphicsView` should be viewed in its entirety as as well as the black line in from the `Vispy` canvas. as well as just see the `QGraphicsView` background color (white) and not the Vispy background color (rgb(86/255,86/255,86/255) ~ gray)

**Code**

```py
    from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
    from vispy.scene import SceneCanvas, visuals, transforms
    import numpy as np
    import sys
    
    
    class VispyCanvasWrapper(QtWidgets.QWidget):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super().__init__(parent)
    
            self.canvas = SceneCanvas(app='pyqt5', bgcolor=(86 / 255, 86/255, 86/255, 0.1))  # Set the background color to almost transparent
            self.grid = self.canvas.central_widget.add_grid()
            self.view_vispy = self.grid.add_view(0, 0, bgcolor=(0, 0, 0, 0.1))  # Set the view's background color to almost transparent
    
            self.view_vispy.camera = "panzoom"
            self.view_vispy.camera.aspect = 1.0
    
            # Set the parent widget of the canvas.native widget to this widget
            self.canvas.native.setParent(self)
            self.geometry = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 500, 500)
            self.canvas.native.setGeometry(self.geometry)
    
            # self.canvas.native.setGeometry(self.geometry)
            self.setObjectName('background_layer')
    
            # create a transparent background
            self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
            self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
            self.setAutoFillBackground(False)
    
            self.this_style_sheet = """
                                  background-color: transparent;
                                  selection-background-color:transparent;
                              """
            self.setStyleSheet(self.this_style_sheet)
            self.canvas.native.setStyleSheet(self.this_style_sheet)
    
    
    class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
        def __init__(self, parent=None):
            super().__init__(parent)
    
            # apply transparent style sheet
            self.this_style_sheet = """
                       background-color: transparent;
                       selection-background-color:transparent;
                   """
    
            self.transparent_viewport_style_sheet = """
                       background-color: transparent;
                   """
    
            # Geometry of the window
            self.geometry = QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 800)
            self.scene_rect_value = QtCore.QRectF(0,0, 200, 200)
            self.setGeometry(self.geometry)
    
            # Create central widget and layout
            central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
            central_widget.setLayout(layout)
            self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
    
            # Graphics view widget (bottom layer)
            self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
            self.graphicsView = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView()
            self.graphicsView.setScene(self.scene)
            self.graphicsView.setSceneRect(self.scene_rect_value)
            layout.addWidget(self.graphicsView, 0, 0)
    
            #vispy widget (top layer)
            self.vispy_canvas = VispyCanvasWrapper(self)
            layout.addWidget(self.vispy_canvas, 0, 0)
    
            # Dummy line
            self.dummy_lines()
    
    
        def dummy_lines(self):
            # add some lines to the line gv
            line_list = [[[0, 0], [250,100] ], [[250, 100], [200,-150]]]
            pen = QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0))
            for line in line_list:
                x1 = line[0][0]
                y1 = -line[0][1]
                x2 = line[1][0]
                y2 = -line[1][1]
                line = QtWidgets.QGraphicsLineItem(x1, y1, x2, y2)
                line.setPen(pen)
                self.scene.addItem(line)
    
            #add line to vispy
            line_data = np.array([[[0, 0], [250,100] ], [[250, 100], [200,-150]]])
            self.line = visuals.Line(line_data, parent=self.vispy_canvas.view_vispy.scene, color='black')
            # Set the zoom extent
            self.vispy_canvas.view_vispy.camera.set_range(x=(0, 200), y=(0, 200))
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        window = MainWindow()
        window.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm missing something, but you have `layout.addWidget(self.vispy_canvas, 0, 0)` and the same `addWidget` for the graphics view. Doesn't the second call overwrite the placement of the first call?

Comment: Hi, @djhoese thanks for reviewing the question.  This second call places the widget in the same space, so it becomes a top layer (vispy) for the bottom layer (QGrapchisView).

Comment: Have you done something like that before and had it work (2 widgets in one cell)? I can't find any documentation that says that that's allowed.

Comment: sure, I did something similar, where I did not know how to sync. 2 graphicsview Both gv are transparent and they let each other graphics item in the canvas, take a look at this post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75947847/two-sync-qgrapchisview-layers-miss-aligned-scene-rect-after-zoom-event-but-alig. Maybe it is not allowed but it has worked in this instance, take into account that I am not a pyqt5 expert, maybe this is not best practice.

Comment: I have no idea if it is supposed to work, but I've never seen it done before. I could see there being an issue between OpenGL (vispy) and the graphics view. Have you/can you try applying that `WA_TranslucentBackground` attribute on the `.native` widget too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some [special properties of `QOpenGLWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglwidget.html#limitations) that make this tricky, but it should be possible (emphasis mine):

> Putting other widgets underneath and making the QOpenGLWidget
> transparent will not lead to the expected results: The widgets
> underneath will not be visible. This is because in practice the
> QOpenGLWidget is drawn before all other regular, non-OpenGL widgets,
> and so see-through type of solutions are not feasible. Other type of
> layouts, like having widgets on top of the QOpenGLWidget, will
> function as expected.
>
> ***When absolutely necessary, this limitation can be overcome by setting
> the Qt::WA_AlwaysStackOnTop attribute on the QOpenGLWidget.*** Be aware
> however that this breaks stacking order, for example it will not be
> possible to have other widgets on top of the QOpenGLWidget, so it
> should only be used in situations where a semi-transparent
> QOpenGLWidget with other widgets visible underneath is required.

So, to take your example (thanks for the well-crafted example!), add `self.canvas.native.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_AlwaysStackOnTop)` in your `VispyCanvasWrapper.__init__`. I put it right next to the other settings:

```
        # create a transparent background
+        self.canvas.native.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_AlwaysStackOnTop)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(False)
```

On my system this seems to produce the desired results and is hopefully enough to at least get you started:
[image: output of the sample script from the OP with the suggested change]

Comment: thank you for responding, I will review the answer fully in a bit.